# How Does the Matcher Glass "Mini Game" Work

Tags: android, google-glass, photosphere

Google recently released a bunch of demo games for google glass, including one called Matcher. On the GDK website, the only description given is:

> We used the Photosphere camera mode to map the surrounding cards and the compact Min3D library on top of OpenGL to render the game.

Can anyone go into more details about how this (or something similar to this) is done. What confuses me the most is the reference to the Photosphere camera mode. Thanks. th

Comment: It would be really interesting to know more about it.  I don't think the mods will leave it open long enough to learn anything good, but thanks for posting and giving me something to look for!